Extension loader pattern only recognizes ext2 instead of ext1 and 2
The code:
interface ExtensionArgs {
    name: string;
}

class Extension<Args extends ExtensionArgs, AUI extends AutumnUI<any>> {
    #name: Args['name'];
    get name(): Args['name'] {
        return this.#name;
    }
    #autumnUI: AUI;
    get autumnUI() {
        return this.#autumnUI;
    }
    constructor(args: Args, aUI: AUI) {
        this.#name = args.name;
        this.#autumnUI = aUI;
    }
}

type Merge<A, B> = {
    [K in keyof A | keyof B]: K extends keyof A & keyof B
        ? A[K] | B[K]
        : K extends keyof B
            ? B[K]
            : K extends keyof A
                ? A[K]
                : never;
};

type AutumnUIBase = {
    extensions: {};
};

type AutumnUI<AUI extends AutumnUIBase> = {
    extensions: AUI['extensions'];
    add: <
        const AU extends AutumnUI<AutumnUIBase>,
        const callBack extends (arg: AU) => Extension<ExtensionArgs, AU>,
        const NewExtension extends ReturnType<callBack>,
    >(
        e: callBack,
    ) => {
        extensions: Merge<AU['extensions'], Record<NewExtension['name'], NewExtension>>;
        add: AutumnUI<AU>['add'];
    };
};

declare const createAutumnUI: AutumnUI<{
    extensions: {};
}>;

function ExtensionLoader<
    const AUI extends AutumnUI<AutumnUIBase>,
    const AUIC extends () => AUI,
    const EARGS extends ExtensionArgs,
>(unusedAUI: AUIC, arg: EARGS): (autumnUI: AUI) => Extension<EARGS, AUI> {
    return (autumnUI: AUI) => new Extension(arg, autumnUI);
}

const ext1 = ExtensionLoader(() => createAutumnUI, { name: 'ext1' });

const ext2 = ExtensionLoader(() => createAutumnUI.add(ext1), { name: 'ext2' });
//It only shows the command from ext2 and not ext1

const step1 = createAutumnUI.add(ext1).extensions.ext1;
const step2_0 = createAutumnUI.add(ext1).add(ext2).extensions.ext1; // should be avaliable here as well
const step2_1 = createAutumnUI.add(ext1).add(ext2).extensions.ext2;

after the
createAutumnUI.add(ext1).add(ext2).extensions

It should be aware of the ext1 and ext2 extensions. but somehow during the .add it loses the type information and only knows about the latest added extension. How can I modify the code so its aware of both extensions?
Playground: https://tsplay.dev/N7D2Gm (67 Lines)
I tried many things and I am expecting that it should work together, the reason why I, in the ExtensionLoader have an unusedAUI is so that while you define you extension you can "depent" on a specific set of extensions to be loaded and build upon them. Later when it actually then loads the extension it will only "build" it once.
